# Migrating from RVM to rbenv, where should gems go?

Tags: ruby, rubygems, rvm, rbenv

I recently switched from RVM to rbenv for Ruby version management because it's easier to understand and I overall like it better.  I've run into problems though when trying to get gems configured correctly.  Despite uninstalling RVM by completely removing the `~/.rvm` directory, ruby-gems are still configured with RVM in mind.

```
$ echo $GEM_PATH
/Users/Alex/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2:/Users/Alex/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2@global
$ echo $GEM_HOME
/Users/Alex/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2
```

`require` has been failing so I've had trouble loading gems into files and I figure it has to do with this inconsistency.

How should I go about fixing this?  Is there a "correct" place to put gems?  Why are gems still looking at the `.rvm` directory? I tried setting `gemhome` in my `.gemrc` to `~/.gem` but I got load errors using the `gem` command in bash.

How should I configure gems now that RVM is out of the picture?

I'm on a Mac running 10.9.3 (Mavericks)

Comment: Maybe you just need to start a new shell/terminal.

Comment: Huh.  That actually did work.  I had restarted the session many times with `exec $SHELL` but completely restarting the terminal app reset those variables.

To be clear, now that `$GEM_HOME` and `$GEM_PATH` are cleared, where are gems installed to?  Should I configure them?

Comment: No, I don't think these configurations are necessary.